# Servidor Telnet em python que mude o título da janela do PuTTY

Tags: python, putty, telnet

alguém tem algum script de servidor Telnet que mude o título da janela do PuTTY de quem se conectar ao mesmo?

Answer (score 2):

A mudança de título da "janela de conexão" não faz parte dos protocolos de Telnet ou de SSH, e nem faz sentido que faça - 
mas o PuTTY emula o comportamento de terminais VT100 - e para esses,, é definido um protocolo acima do conteúdo para mudança de título da janela.

A sequência de escape ANSI "OSC 0;  ST" pode trocar o título da janela que se conectou ao servidor - basta que essa sequência seja impressa no terminal conectado.  Se a conexão é para se ter um login cin prompt shell do sistema operacional, uma forma de fazer isso é alterar a variável de ambiente $PS1, e incluir essa string dentro do próprio prompt.

Sem saber mais dos seus objetivos com a conexão telnet, e o que ela tem a ver com Python é difícil ser mais específico.

Se sua conexão Telnet estiver imprimindo a saída do programa Python, a sequência acima pode ser exibida com:

```
print("\x1b]0;{}\x1b\\".format("Seu titulo aqui"))
```

(Em Python, o '\x1b' é a representação do caracter ESC, a sequência 'ESC + ]" é o comando "OSC" - "Operating System Command",e o comando "0;" o comando para mudar o título do terminal. A sequência "ESC \" é o mesmo que "ST" ("STRING TERMINATOR"), que termina o comando). O "{}" é usado pelo próprio método `.format` do Python para substituir o título desejado, deixando bem separado o conteúdo que você quer colocar no título dos comandos necessários para isso.

A docuementação completa dos caracteres de controle ANSI está aqui:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code